# Is this a bug? Using a touch input (With mouse input on) on a button but nothing is done

Tags: construct-2

I am using a button to transit to another layer. But I can't transit to that layer. I am using construct 3.

When I click on that button
onTouched an object (the object is that button) -> Go to layer (Layer02)

But nothing happens. I am using Touch but I have set the mouse input on. I used other object to try such as text field, and it works. Everything works except when I used button.

Is it a bug? Or I am not doing it right. The variables you see in the picture are for debugging purposes.

These are my events:

[image: Screenshot of my events]

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to "transit to another **layout**" (not layer)

On your screenshot I see all your events are OK. If you add `Touch` doesn't need add Mouse (you can use the mouse to simulate touch on browser).

I create a new project with the same events and works correctly, I attach a `.c3p` so you can try it.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7x1r27rs5a6k5d0/button_layout.c3p?dl=0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, really the answer it's: all seems it's ok, so... I attach an example with the same code and working as expected. Maybe @del can show us the rest of the project or maybe provide a .c3p file for testing and find the correct answer.